# run Qt - QWT on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

1. Build and installation

```
qmake qwt.pro
make
sudo make install
```

2. Configure

2.1. add the following lines to `.bashrc`:

```
        export QWT_ROOT="/usr/local/qwt-6.2.0"
        QT_PLUGIN_PATH="${QWT_ROOT}/plugins:$QT_PLUGIN_PATH"
        export QT_PLUGIN_PATH
```

2.2. add the line to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/qwt.conf`: `/usr/local/qwt-6.2.0/lib`

3. Imput to console: `qmake -set QMAKEFEATURES ${QWT_ROOT}/features`
4. Create project

#### DeleteMe.pro

```
QT += quick

#add QWT
CONFIG += qwt

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qwt-6.2.0/include
LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-6.2.0/lib -lqwt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
...
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QwtPlot>
#include <QwtText>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QwtPlot plot(QwtText("Qwt example"));
    plot.setGeometry(0,0,640, 300);
    plot.show();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile, i got the errors:

```
:-1: error: main.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN7QWidget4showEv@@Qt_5'
:-1: error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

Please help me to run the program

Comment: I think your problem is `QT += quick` but I am not a QMake expert. I think it should be `QT += widgets` instead. Your code is not using QtQuick or qml